# Calculus and Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: calculus

If I have the function

$u(x_1,x_2) = (x_1-a_1)^{1/2}(x_2-a_2)^{1/2}$

If I take the derivative of the above with respect to $x_1$, would it equal $1/2 (x_1)^{-1/2} (x_2-a_2)^{1/2}$?

And wrt to $x_2$ = $1/2(x_1-a_1)^{1/2}(x_2)^{-1/2}$

Please help.

Comment: Okay so i was wrong above then?

Comment: Now if i had to take it a step further and divide ∂u∂xi=(xj−aj)1/22(xi−ai)1/2 below by the partial derivate of xj with the right hand side equaling p1/p2. Would I get x2 to equal p1x1 - p1a1-a2 / p2

Answer (score 0):

You can express the answer as follows: $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} = \dfrac{(x_j-a_j)^{1/2}}{2(x_i-a_i)^{1/2}}$.

If further that: $\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}}{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}} = \dfrac{x_2-a_2}{x_1-a_1} = \dfrac{p_1}{p_2} \to x_2 = \dfrac{p_1x_1 - p_1a_1 + p_2a_2}{p_2}$